# How to sort a csv column that includes both letters and digits in python?

Tags: python, sorting, csv

[Problem:] I am having trouble sorting a column that includes both letters and digits.

[Input]
My column looks like this:
Reference

```
Test1
Test2
Test11
```

[Code]

```
import csv
import operator
sample = open (r'test.csv','r')
csv1 = csv.reader(sample, delimiter = ',')
sort = sorted (csv1,key=operator.itemgetter(154))
```

[Current output]

```
Test1
Test11
Test2
```

[Desired output]

```
Test1
Test2
Test11
```

Therefore can u please share a hint on this.

Take care

Answer (score 0):

You can use re to find the digits and cast to int :

```
import re

sort = sorted(csv1,key=lambda x: int(re.search("\d+",x[154]).group()))
```

If you have some strings without digits:

import re

```
sort = sorted(csv1,key=lambda x: x[154] if x.isalpha() else int(re.search("\d+",x[154]).group()))
```

Comment: OP was using `operator.itemgetter(154)` as the key so minor adjustment needed: `lambda x: int(re.search("\d+",x[154]).group())`

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for quick reply. I've tried your approach and I got: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'.  Current code is: import csv
import operator
sample = open (r'test.csv','r')
csv1 = csv.reader(sample, delimiter = ',')
sort = sorted(csv1,key=lambda x: int(re.search("\d+",x[154]).group()))

Comment: @ HappyLeapSecond; yes the code: "import re; sorted(lst, key=lambda x: int(re.findall(r'\d+$', x)[0]))" (from duplicate question) works for list, but it seems I cannot get it to work on my column. I will try to figure out what I am missing

Comment: @serte. Then there are values that have no digits in the string

Comment: Yes. The "Reference" column header has no digits. I will try: to skip header or append "0" to column header.

Comment: Yesm just header =  next(csv1) will skip the header